# Issue with receiving imap email in redmine

Tags: redmine

My incoming emails keep getting ignored and not filed into the correct project. What am I missing here?

```
rake -f /home/kickapps/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap \
RAILS_ENV="production" \
host=imap.gmail.com \
ssl=SSL \
port=993 \
move_on_success=FILED \
move_on_failure=IGNORED \
username=redmine@kitops.com \
password=*************** \
unknown_user=accept \
no_permission_check=1 \
project=test \
allow_override=project,tracker
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the email become read in gmail then try adding --trace at the end of your rake parameters (you should get a rake error). The email must be unread/new at gmail box or it won't be read by the rake because it thinks it already read it.

Another gotcha: 993 blocked by firewall between redmine and gmail.

Check the rails log/production.log right after running the rake - check if there's some error message about the mail.

Assuming the rake task is reading and changing the status in gmail, then it might be the parameters. I notice your **ssl is different** from what I had.

```
rake -f /home/kickapps/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap \
RAILS_ENV="production" \
host=imap.gmail.com \
ssl=1 \ # it's 1 on my install -- double check
port=993 \
username=redmine@kitops.com \
password=*************** \
project=test \ # must be the project identfier not the name
status=assigned \ # must be a status used in the project, check popups in redmine
unknown_user=accept \ #haven't tried this
no_permission_check=1 \ # or this
allow_override=project,tracker # or this
```

Comment: It is getting the email from gmail. It is just marking it as ignored and not creating a new ticket.